# Наследование абстрактного класса в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++, наследование

Изучаю тему наследования по практикуму учебника 2010 года. Там есть пример, который я взял для изучения вопроса наследования, где используется базовый абстрактный класс. Я создавал объект от абстрактного для унаследованного класса (поправьте если не прав) и у меня ничего не получается, компилятор упорно стоит на том что есть ошибки.

**Базовый класс AString.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ASTRING_H
#define ASTRING_H
#include<string>
class AString
{
    public:
    virtual ~AString() {}
    virtual const std::string& GetName() = 0;
    virtual const std::string& GetVal()const = 0;
    virtual int GetSize()const = 0;
};
```

**Унаследованный SymbString.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "AString.h"

class SymbString :public AString 
{
    public:
    SymbString(std::string _name) :name(_name) {}
    SymbString(std::string _name, std::string _val) :name(_name), val(_val) {}
    const std::string& GetName()const { return name; }
    const std::string& GetVal()const { return val; }
    int GetSize()const { return val.size(); }
private:
    std::string name, val;
};
```

И файл где можно создавать объектов столько, сколько хочет пользователь:

```
....

AString* pNewObj;
switch (item)
{
case 1: pNewObj = new SymbString(name, value);// тут подчеркивает и пишет "использование 
//объекта абстрактного типа класса "SymbString" не допускается чисто
 //виртуальная функция функцию "AString::GetName" не имеет оператора переопределения " 
    break;
case 2: if (!IsHexStrVal(value))
{
    cout << "Error!" << endl;
    return;
}
        pNewObj = new HexString(name, value);// выводит тоже самое только для этого случая
        break;
}
```

То что написал компилятор ("использование объекта абстрактного типа класса "`SymbString`" не допускается чисто виртуальная функция функцию "`AString::GetName`" не имеет оператора переопределения") вызывает непонимание что от меня хотят. Разве для `SymbString` и `HexString` я не могу создавать объекты?

Переписывал с учебника код слово в слово.

Не понятно также что означает первое `const` перед string в следующей строчке:
`virtual const std::string& GetVal()const = 0;`, какова его роль?

Comment: Думаю, будет полезно указать по какому учебнику вы это проходите, возможно, другие тоже столкнутся с такой проблемой.

Comment: Кстати, #pragma once делает то же самое, что и include guards после нее (ifndef-def), так что что-то из этого можно убрать.

Comment: @free_ze, в моем случае не помогло, только со стражами включения, что вы описали выше

Comment: @СемёнШелухин Не может такого быть. Какой у вас компилятор?

Comment: @free_ze, использую IDE VS2015, а там какой не знаю.

Comment: @СемёнШелухин Тогда проблем быть не должно, она отлично понимает pragma once.

Comment: @free_ze, я тоже так думал, но старый дедовский способ от Страуструпа оказался верным

Comment: @СемёнШелухин способ этот еще с сишных дострауступовых времен) Сейчас компиляторы умеют парсить include guards и нет никакого замедления компиляции, но писать одну строчку проще, чем три, так что я бы поискал проблему на вашем месте.

Comment: @free_ze, в этом же учебнике, по которому я учусь автор пишет что это Страуструп советует), но спорить не буду. Поковыряться бы следовало, но у меня community версия, поэтому я думаю багов будет предостаточно, к тому же #pragma once, как я слышал применима только для создания приложений для Windows платформы в среде VS.

Comment: @EgorSmolyakov, C/C++. Структурное и объектно-ориентированное программирование. Практикум. Татьяна Павловская, Юрий Щупак. Как   оказалось в учебнике const присутствовал, но были другие ошибки.

Comment: @СемёнШелухин если этот учебник того же года издания, по которому еще я учился, написанный под C++03, то не удивительно)

Comment: @СемёнШелухин pragma once когда-то была лучше (компилятор в первый раз делал себе отметку в таблице и ему не требовалось на самом деле препроцессить файл повторно в следующий раз, что неиллюзорно ускоряло сборку), но специфичен для Visual Studio, потому не использовался отцами опенсорса =) Но сейчас все современные компиляторы умеют в эту директиву. Где-то читал, что GCC кроме всего научился аналогично использовать include guards. Если необходимо инклудить файл целиком лишь однажды, разницы нет никакой, кроме синтаксиса.

Comment: @free_ze, спасибо, но у меня возник еще вопрос. Не понятно что означает первое const перед string в следующей строчке: virtual const std::string& GetVal()const = 0;, какова его роль?

Comment: @СемёнШелухин Вы возвращаете тип const std::string&, т.е. константную ссылку на ваши данные класса. Если бы вы попытались сделать тип просто std::string&, то компилятор вас бы заругал, т.к. метод сам помечен const, т.е. он не должен менять состояние объекта ни напрямую, ни давать возможность это сделать (через неконстантную ссылку или неконстантный указатель (то есть который указывает на нечто изменяемое)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы определяете новую версию `GetName() const` (константную), а не переопределяете абстрактную `GetName()`

Comment: Помогло, не понял что надо было поставить const для чисто виртуальной функции абстрактного класса. Теперь ругается компоновщик, но это уже другая история.

Comment: Плюс нужно проставить кое где в заголовочных файлах стражи включения #ifndef... #define.. #endif.. Будет работать.

Comment: @СемёнШелухин если компилятор поддерживает *c++11*, следует воспользоваться помощью спецификатора `override`.